# error installing postgresql 9.3 and postgis 2.1 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, postgis

I was trying to install PostgreSQL-9.3 and postgis-2.1 using this command

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib postgis postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
```

I got this error

- The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
  2016-03-18 10:54:56 IST FATAL:  private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" has group or world access
  2016-03-18 10:54:56 IST DETAIL:  File must be owned by the database user or root, must have no write permission for "group", and must have no permissions for "other".

I searched for the error and got some solutions from the below links

[PostgreSQL won't start: "server.key" has group or world access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087683/postgresql-wont-start-server-key-has-group-or-world-access)

I tried the solution but this gave me error permission denied..

and the second one I tried was

```
chmod 640 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

this gave error operation not permitted. Please help me with this..

Comment: Maybe `sudo` before `chmod` could help.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned that.. but I already tried that

Comment: and the main error still persist

Comment: send a `ls -la` from `data`